# Entity Framework : add entity to database skip added to specific table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have used all day trying to find out what I should do with this problem. The problem is that when I add a "Reservation" entity to the database using EF, it adds something unnecessary to one of the tables that I do not need. I'm not sure if its my data model that causes the problem.

Have created a data model that look like this:

[image]

There is a many to many relationship between a reservation and a room. Many reservations should hold 1 contact person only.

My models look like this:

**Reservation**: (have left out unnecessary properties)

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int ReservationID { get; set; }
    public int ContactPersonID { get; set; }

    public virtual ContactPerson ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Room { get; set; }

    public Reservation()
    {
        Room = new List<Room>();
        ContactPerson = new ContactPerson();
    }
}
```

**Room**: (have left out unnecessary properties)

```
public class Room
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

**ContactPerson**: (have left out unnecessary properties)

```
public class ContactPerson
{
    public int ContactPersonID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have created a `DataContext` class that looks like this:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DataContext")
    {
    }

    // DbSet to bookings
    public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactPerson> ContactPersons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    public void MarkAsModified(Reservation item)
    {
        Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void CreateReservation(Reservation item)
    {
        Reservations.Add(item);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Room).WithMany(i => i.Reservations)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ReservationID")
            .MapRightKey("RoomID")
            .ToTable("RoomReservation"));
    }
}
```

Because it's a many to many relationship between room and reservation, a shared Table will be created.

I have created some test data for the application, and updated the database using migrations. The `Room` model should create a table of rooms in the hotel, like this data:

```
 var rooms = new List<Room>
        {
            new Room {RoomNumber = "101", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = true, Smoking = false},
            new Room {RoomNumber = "102", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = true, Smoking = false},
            new Room {RoomNumber = "103", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = false, Smoking = false},
            new Room {RoomNumber = "104", Beds = 2, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Double, Minibar = true, Occupied = false, Smoking = true},             
        };

rooms.ForEach(b => context.Rooms.AddOrUpdate(b));
context.SaveChanges();
```

This test data should be generated when the application starts. The problem is when I add a reservation using the `Reservations.Add` from the `DataContext`, it adds new rooms to the `Room` table.

What I want is only to update the reservation table, the contact table and the shared table of what rooms are on the reservation.

So if a reservation has room 101 (ID 1) and room 102 (ID 2), these ID should be used inside the shared table.

For some reason when I add a reservation and the reservation has one room with ID = 1 (room 101), it adds this room with a new generated ID (ID = 5, because there is already 4 rooms in the table), which it shouldn't do. It also updates the shared table and uses this ID = 5, where it should have used the ID = 1.

Have tried to explain this best as possible, hope someone can tell me my next move. Good day :)

Comment: Did you check what the Reservation's Room property is when calling `CreateReservation`? Is the room loaded via EF using the same DBContext or is it a new instance (e.g. you add `new Room()` somewhere to the Reservation's Room collection)? You might want to take a look at the reservation's Room Collection property and and inspect their State (Entity Frameworks Changetracking State, if it is new, this might cause the insert)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will update the post with what I do before posting.

Answer (score 0):

a quick glance and I've noticed that your model is really complicated. do you really navigation properties from Room and Customer to Reservations?

write (add, update, delete) operations for a complex object graph is a pain in entity framework, especially when the objects are disconnected.

simplify your model and remove ICollection Reservations from Room and Customer.

add additional methods to your data access layer to get reservations by room and by customer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem that was causing the issue. As the kind Bernhard Kircher explained to me, that there was something wrong with the context.

Solved the problem by, getting the list of all rooms, filter it so only room that was being selected could be in the list.

Add that list to the reservation. Some how it does work, so I guess there were something about the state.

```
public bool Execute(Reservation reservation)
    {
        //Add correct rooms to reservation;
        List<Room> roomsEntities = new List<Room>();

        foreach (var room in reservation.Room)
        {
            var roomsFound = _db.Rooms.Where(r => r.ID == room.ID).ToList();

            foreach (var ro in roomsFound)
            {
                roomsEntities.Add(ro);
            }
        }

        //Add correct rooms to entity.
        reservation.Room = roomsEntities;

        try
        {
            _db.CreateReservation(reservation);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Have added the code for other to look that will experience the same kind of problem :)

Comment: I am glad my comment helped you, but your code seems to be a Workaround. Maybe your datamodel is not ideal (which @KMC suggests) but I don't know enough about your model. But what I think is wrong is the fact, that you get a Reservation object with existing rooms in it, but you have to reload them from database to make it work correctly. This Looks like your room entities are not attached to the current DbContext (_db) and this might be the cause why EF tries to create new instances on the DB. In my experience such "Manual" Solutions/workarounds only cause Problems in the long run.